# Return null values IN clause mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, in-clause

Print not found when there is no data found in database. For example in my database I do not have `56443` therefore it should print `'not found'`

```
SELECT uid, (CASE WHEN (u.uid = null) THEN 'not found' ELSE 'found' END) as result
FROM (SELECT uid
            FROM users
            WHERE uid IN (1,2,56443,3)) as u;
```

Getting result as follows

```
+--------+--------+
| uid    | result|
+--------+--------+
| 1      | found | 
| 2      | found |
| 3      | found |
+--------+--------+
```

I am also expecting `not found` row with `56443`

Comment: You sould use u.uid is null instead of u.uid = null, as null values can not be compared using = operator in sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a different approach. You will need to create a inline view with all the values using the UNION ALL, and then left join it with the users table:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c38d26/7)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT a.uid, (CASE WHEN (u.uid is null) THEN 'not found' ELSE 'found' END) as     result
FROM (select 1 as UID FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      select 2 as UID FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      select 56443 as UID FROM dual
      UNION ALL
      select 3 as UID FROM dual) as a
LEFT JOIN users u on a.uid = u.uid
```

**[Results]**:

```
|   UID |    result |
|-------|-----------|
|     1 |     found |
|     2 |     found |
|     3 |     found |
| 56443 | not found |
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it

Comment: The query works for this particular case. If you have a different set of values then you have to form this query dynamically otherwise you won't be able to utilize this query. Better do this dummy row generations in application level. @mubeen

Comment: @1000111 Thank you for your worry. But query is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are comparing a value with null aka. unknown. Always use the IS operator when comparing to null values.
    CASE WHEN (u.uid is null) THEN 'not found' ELSE 'found' END) as     result

Try this instead (updated answer):

```
SELECT u2.uid, (CASE WHEN (u1.uid is null) THEN 'not found' ELSE 'found' END) 
as     result
FROM users u1
RIGHT JOIN 
(select 1 as uid union all
 select 2 as uid union all
 select 3 as uid union all
 select 56443 as uid
) u2
on u1.uid = u2.uid
```

Comment: Try it, but same result :( .

Comment: Nope, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c38d26/1 because there still is no 56443 in users

Comment: This also worked! Thank you.. But I can mark only one answer

Comment: I noticed the other answer. Awesome.. It's fine you got the correct answer. Cheers!