# returning null or empty string in "IN CLAUSE" mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query :

```
SELECT * from tbl WHERE id = 1 AND option IN (1,2,3)
```

table :

```
+-------+---------+-------+
| id    | option  | votes |
+-------+---------+-------+
|   1   |    1    |  100  |
|   1   |    2    |  150  |
+-------+---------+-------+
```

As option no.3 doesnt exist yet in the table, i want it to return null / empty string, so i can set 'votes' to 0 in my php code.

Currently it only gives me rows of option 1 & 2 as expected.

Comment: You can do it in your PHP if your query does not return any data for the given option

Comment: What `IN` does is to match any id you've provided against the ones in your database. All id's in the `IN` don't necessarily have to be in your database. Think of it like an `OR` statement.

Comment: And if you need extra option row, you must do it from PHP code, as you are getting rows for 1 and 2, if you don't have 3, assign votes to 0 in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return null values IN clause mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324503/return-null-values-in-clause-mysql)

Comment: @ShaunakShukla what i'm trying to do is to insert empty element to the result array whenever the option is not found in DB, then loop through the result array to set empty values/null to 0 in php.

i dont know if im doing this right

Comment: @Akintunde i see, but is there any way to force this ?

Comment: @jsnalf, I am going to write an answer for you according to rishipuri's comment.

Comment: @jsnalf, please check my answer, if it is proper for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from tbl t1
RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT 1 AS opt UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 AS opt UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 AS opt UNION ALL
) t2
ON t1.option = t2.opt
WHERE t1.id = 1
```

Comment: ill try to implement it with dynamically generated options.

thanks for your help